# Finding the extreme points and draw a line when extreme points is detected

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How to draw vertical line when the extreme point is detected and put some measurement like (inches,mm, cm etc):

[image]

This is the result of the code:
[image: This is the result of the code]

The below start point must draw a cv2.circle extreme point in the drawContour not in the `cv2.rectangle`:

[image: The below start point must draw a cv2.circle extreme point in the drawContour not in the cv2.rectangle]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, threshold
image = cv2.imread('banana4.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Obtain outer coordinates
left = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
right = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
top = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
bottom = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

# Draw dots onto image
cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), 2)
cv2.circle(image, left, 8, (0, 50, 255), -1)
cv2.circle(image, right, 8, (0, 255, 255), -1)
cv2.circle(image, top, 8, (255, 50, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(image, bottom, 8, (255, 255, 0), -1)

print('left: {}'.format(left))
print('right: {}'.format(right))
print('top: {}'.format(top))
print('bottom: {}'.format(bottom))
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I mean when the extreme points is being it will draw a vertical line.

Comment: I'm just create an account so I can create a another question because it's limited.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple questions and problems here.

1. You should decrease the min value for the binary threshold in order to get rid of the shadow.

   `thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]`
2. You already have the bounding box top/bottom/left/right, so you can draw a rectangle using [cv2.rectangle](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle).

   `cv2.Rectangle(image, (left[0], top[1]), (right[0], bottom[1]), (0, 255, 0), 2)`
3. If you don't know any information about the camera or the object itself, it is not possible to give an estimate about the size.